# Map Tool Compatibility in IE & Chrome

Tags: arcgis-server, arcobjects

I have a customized tool developed and running on ArcGIS server 10.0. using Web ADF
The tool is used to draw a rectangle on map and mark selection to the selected area in a Graphics layer.
This tool works fine in IE (obviously for IE11, I have to set the compatibility mode on and set to the browse page).
But when I try the same tool in Chrome, the rectangle drawn enlarges to some extent on the map and selects unwanted area too.

Is there any map rendering option available in ArcObjects 10.0 to resolve the issue.